# Upon executing a selenium test, spin new Windows VM, execute commands, then exit?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, virtual-machine

I am running a Mac but need to test Web applications in IE.  Ideally, I would love to be able to execute a selenium command on my box, and it would spin up a VM (VirtualBox, VMWare, something like that), run the commands in IE, and then exit the VM once I'm done.  Is that possible?  If not, does anyone else have a better idea of how to run selenium commands in a Windows environment from a box that is not Windows?  My commands are in Python 2.7, if that matters.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements shall be possible to fulfill.

Selenium can be using "Selenium Server" and your python code using `selenium` package shall be able talking to it - it uses http protocol for such a remote control.

Selenium server is using Java, and as it is started, it shows url on which it awaits commands.

These urls can be then used in your python code when constructing driver for your browser, there you specify url of remote Selenim server and shall be able continuing as if you would work locally.

[Description how to connect is here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html#using-selenium-with-remote-webdriver).

[image: Conceptual schema]

Feel free to comment or reply to me how it went, it sounds very interesting but I do not have any real experience with that so far.